# No success by using strpos when searching a string

Tags: php, string, strpos

I have the following code/string:
`$ids="#222#,#333#,#555#";`

When I'm searching for a part using:

```
if(strpos($ids,"#222#"))
```

it won't find it. But when I'm searching without the hashes, it works using:

```
if(strpos($ids,"222"))
```

I've already tried using `strval` for the search parameter, but this won't work also.

Comment: have you tried escaping the hashes? (strpos($ids,"\#222\#")).

Answer (score 6):

`strpos` starts counting from 0, and returns false if nothing is found.  You need to check if it's false with `===` like this...

```
if (strpos($ids, '#222#') === false) // not found
```

Or use `!==` if you want the opposite test...

```
if (strpos($ids, '#222#') !== false) // found
```

See the [PHP Manual entry](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for more information

Comment: @user1824136 glad to have helped!  Don't forget to mark the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not explecitely testing for FALSE when using strpos. Use it like this:

```
if(strpos($string, '#222#') !== FALSE) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```

---

Explanation: You are using it like this:

```
if(strpos($string, '#222#')) {
    // found
}
```

What is the problem with this? Answer: `strpos()` will return the position in string where the substring was found. In you case `0` as its at the beginning of the string. But `0` will be treated as false by PHP unless you issue an explicit check with `===`  or `!==`.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. `strpos()` returns 0 because the string you're searching for is at the beginning of the word. You need to do an equality search:

Update your `if()` statement as follows:

```
if(strpos($ids, '#222') !== false)
{
    // string was found!
}
```

Comment: `strpos()` returns `false` if the string's not found.. not -1

Comment: I realized after hitting submit. Updated.

Comment: In every other language on God's green earth this is correct. Unfortunately, PHP uses `FALSE` as a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Comment: Where did you find that strpos retunrs -1 if target is not found?

Comment: @Eineki Interesting side question, "and what do you do when that happens?"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
$ids="#222#,#333#,#555#";
if(strpos($ids,"#222#") !== false)
{
    echo "found";
}
```

You should use  `!==` because the position of `'#222#'` is the `0th (first)` character.